# Python discord bot send message in a channel

Tags: python, discord, bots, twitch

I'm trying to run a very simple program: it should check for a string in a link, and in case of a true or false result it should send a different message to a discord channel. The part that verifies the link works, the problem is the part that sends the message, I tried to do it again in different ways but I can't get it to work, this is the code:

```
@client.command()
async def check_if_live():
    global live
    contents = requests.get('https://www.twitch.tv/im_marcotv').content.decode('utf-8')
    channel = client.get_channel(1005529902528860222)
    if 'isLiveBroadcast' in contents: 
        print('live')
        live = True
        await channel.send('live')
    else:
        print('not live')
        live = False
        await channel.send('not live')
```

In other parts of the code where I send a message in response to a command using `await message.channel.send("message")`everything works as expected.

I have done a lot of research but can't find anything useful.

*edit:
With the code above the error is `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'` on the line `await channel.send('not live')`, if i try to do as suggested by Artie Vandelay inserting `await client.fetch_channel(1005529902528860222)` before `channel = client.get_channel(1005529902528860222)` on the inserted line I have an error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'request'`.

Since I think that at this point it may have a certain value, I also insert the code sections about the client variable.

```
client = discord.Client()
load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('TOKEN')
#all bot code
client.run(TOKEN)
```

I also tried this:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('TOKEN')
@bot.command()
#all bot code
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Both methods return errors

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: If the error is that you channel is `None`, then it could mean that your channel is not in the bot's cache. `client.get_channel` only looks in the cache and returns the channel *if it's there*, otherwise it returns `None`. You can actively fetch the channel regardless of whether it's in the cache by using `await client.fetch_channel(1005529902528860222)`.

Comment: hey, if you're just making a bot that will check if a twitch channel is live, you're better off focusing more on the actual logic behind checking, and sending the notification via the webhook, instead of centering the entire script around discord.py

Comment: Actually the bot also does other things besides twitch notifications (mainly it sends messages in response to commands) the recognition method for twitch works great, my problem is just sending a message in a specific channel.

Answer (score 0):

Double check if your channel id is correct.

Also try using

```py
.text
```

instead of

```py
.content.decode('utf-8')
```

if it still does not work, please send your error message, so we can see what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I answer my question because I found a solution, instead of using `@bot.command` I used `@bot.event async def on_ready()`, and now it works, I hope this answer can be useful to someone else who has this same problem.